# Why and where to create a loopback file for live persistence session?

Tags: live-cd, iso, testing

I currently help QA team in ISO testing, but I stumbled on a test-case that required some extra research.  I just learned about persistence from this [wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence).

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to "Using a loop-back file." Since I will be ISO testing on a Mac, I don't know if it's appropriate to make the file in the root of the partition of my Ubuntu computer.

If the loop-back file is indeed necessary, how can I use it for my Mac computer? If it is as simple as copy-paste, I'll be surprised.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Loopback "file" is actually a **device** file like those located in /dev/

So it's a special file and you should not copy it to some other computer. Loopback device is a special device in linux and I'm not sure that Mac shares the same mechanism of mounting iso files.

You can use FuseISO (http://sourceforge.net/projects/fuseiso/) to mount .iso files via fuse system instead of using kernel module for iso (which requires loopback device)